# How to input value into rc-slider handle

Tags: reactjs, slider, rc-slider

I need to input current value of slider into slider handle (button). Is it possible to do so in rc-slider?

I tried to use rc-tooltip, but it is not what I want

Current slider code:

```
<Slider
    vertical
    min={50}
    defaultValue={100}
    max={150}
    step={2}
    dots
    onChange={onSliderChange}
    trackStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#06080E' }}
    railStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#06080E' }}
    handleStyle={{
      height: 25,
      width: 70,
      marginLeft: -14,
      marginTop: -9,
      backgroundColor: '#075DFF',
      border: 'none',
      borderRadius: 3,
      boxShadow: 'none !imporatnt',
    }}
    dotStyle={{
      width: 30,
      border: 'none',
      borderRadius: 0,
      height: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#666',
    }}
    activeDotStyle={{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    }}
  />
```

Current slider image:

[image: two muppets]

I need slider value inside of "blue slider button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

Use handle prop in Slider component where you can specify function which will return Handle component with own children:

```
const { Handle } = Slider;

const sliderHandle = (e) => {
  const { value } = e;
  return (
    <Handle {...e}>{value}</Handle>
  );
};
```

Result:

[image: Result]